# How to set String variable in an Matrix using JAMA?

Tags: java, string, matrix, jama

I try to solve binomial equation (d= a0 + a1 * t + a2 * t*t) by least square adjustment (Xcap=(A^T A)^-1 A^T L). I use "JAMA" lib. to construct and calculate matrices (A: design matrix, Xcap: Unknown parameters matrix and L : measurment matrix). So, I cannot set design matrix's entries with a String variable. Could you please sueggest me an idea?